# What's the use of lightmap?

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine

For starter, I know what a lightmap is, what to be gained by using it, and how to implement it. What I don't get is, if you have dynamically moving objects, which won't be able to generate a lightmap, you still need a light source to project their shadows. So, what would be gained by lightmap if we still need a light for the ones that won't get any lightmapping (ie. dynamic objects)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you don't use realtime shadows** (it's an option, often on mobile), than you can have more or less 2 approach for dynamic objects:

- Use lightmap data baked into probes to approximate per-vertex lighting (no need to have realtime light). It's an approximation but can work on some contexts.
- Use real-time lights only on dynamic objects, so you'll improve the look of those without sacrifice any performance on static ones, which can use only baked lights

**If you need dynamic shadows** casted by dynamic objects on static baked ones, than you still can benefits from lightmaps for several reasons:

- Even if additional lighting passes are necessary to project shadows on static lightmapped objects, probably not all objects will be affected by shadow, but only the ones relatively close to the dynamic shadow caster object. So you still can save a lot of GPU time.
- Lightmaps (especially on forward render path), allow to produce complex light scenarios, that would be otherwise impossible to achieve in realtime. Dynamic objects, doesn't need to be affected by all baked lights, but eventually only from the more important ones. This way you can have a limited amount of drawcalls for a really good looking static environments, and a limited number of "important" lights affecting the dynamic objects

> if you have dynamically moving objects, which won't be able to
>   generate a lightmap, you still need a light source to project their
>   shadows.

That's true. But:

1. you save computing shading of static lightmapped objects because light won't affect them
2. as already said before, projected shadow will be casted on a limited set of objects

Comment: I see. That makes sense. But what if I have multiple static objects of the same model that will be pooled (if they were out of the camera's viewport) and just reused if it is inside the viewport?

Comment: @Bawenang Rukmoko Pardian Putra: what do you mean?

Comment: Say, if I have 1000 cabbages which are a part of the environment spread across the level, but I just instantiate 10 of them because max only 10 should be rendered (ie. the cabbages are spread not too closely)  and just use those 10 cabbages every time it is needed to be rendered (by moving & rotating one of the out of sight ones to the rendered position). So the actual representation of the cabbages is just an empty node / gameobject with transform. Or should I just instantiate them all and just let the culling system take care of it?

Comment: LM works on static objects only. If you move an object after it's been lightmapped the light texture wrapped on it won't be consistent with the surrounding environment. So you need all your objects to be instantiated (at least during bake)

Comment: Yeah, but because I will only use 10 objects that will be moved around if needed, won't the lightmap be wrong?

Comment: In the general case, if you move a lightmapped object its lighting will be wrong. Consider with LM light bounces and you'll get a sort of GI, so the object lighting is influenced by the nearby environment. If the results might be acceptable depends on you.